# Don't group if value is empty

Tags: mysql

I've a table with values like:

```
row   item_id   device_token
1     1         1234
2     2         2345
3     1         
4     2         
5     1         
6     1         1234
```

I would like to select all values, but group them by item_id and device_token.

> SELECT item_id, device_token FROM hits GROUP BY item_id, device_token

Grouping the above data would results in 4 rows, as row 1,6 and 3,5 would be combined. Can I make a query which does not group the rows where the device_token is empty/null (row 3 and 5)?

Comment: grouping by device_token should produce 3 rows. 1234, 2345, and empty - not 4.

Comment: @MarcB: `GROUP BY item_id, device_token` - it's really four rows

Comment: Why would you want such result? How is row 3 different than row 5? (except for the `row` value which you don't want to get?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want the rows where device_token is empty this is easy - just use a simple `WHERE` clause as others have suggested.

And if you want to have both, those with matching device_token grouped and those without a device token as single rows, you can combine two queries with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT item_id, device_token 
  FROM hits 
  WHERE device_token IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY item_id, device_token 
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id, device_token 
  FROM hits 
  WHERE device_token IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT item_id, device_token FROM hits WHERE device_token IS NOT NULL GROUP BY item_id, device_token
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group them - you just need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`. like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, device_token FROM hits WHERE device_token IS NOT NULL
```

Do you want the empty fields to be present?

Do you have other aggregate fields present that may require grouping?

Please specify some more details - maybe that's not exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, and ordered, try something like this.

```
SELECT item_id, device_token
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, device_token
    FROM hits
    WHERE device_token IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY item_id, device_token

    UNION ALL

    SELECT item_id, device_token
    FROM hits
    WHERE device_token IS NULL
) AS a
ORDER BY item_id, device_token
```